# HTML: Wrap lines of two rows with space reserved for each row on the new line

Tags: html, flexbox, word-wrap

I am attempting to use flexbox or another technology to create a kind of word processor.

Lines in the word processor would consist of two rows, and would wrap onto new lines while reserving space for both rows on the new line.

```
    <span class="remark" style="display: inline">
      <span style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: wrap">
        <div class="topic" style="font-size: 12px; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: green">This is the secondary row.</div>
        <div class="text" style="font-size: 18px; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: red;">This is the primary row. Ideally, once either row reaches the end of the container, the stack will wrap to the next line, reserving space for both rows, creating effectively two sets of rows of alternating Christmas colors instead of one line of green and three lines of red, ho ho ho!</div>
      </span>
    </span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4j7yqrnm/

The goal is basically to wrap a two-lane "road" filled with text to a new line whenever either of the lanes is filled with "cars" of text.

Below is a rough picture of what I mean. I am trying to make lines of two rows that expand whenever text is added inside either one of them. The rows would wrap and keep the same order on the new line.

=========================================================================
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa=================================                                         aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Further edit: I am trying to implement exactly what this question is asking for, except in html/css/js and not TeX: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136121/possible-to-wrap-multiple-rows-within-a-column-at-one-time

Thank you!

Comment: Please post the code you have already tried, and an explanation of how it is not working.

Comment: Please see the link to the fiddle. The problem is that the primary row wraps directly to the new line, rather than leaving space for the secondary row and wrapping the stack as a whole. Thank you!

Comment: I don't get it... you are using `column` flex direction and `wrap` on top of it... wrapping not happening right now...

Comment: Right, my thinking was to put the two rows in a column so they would be adjacent, and then wrap to a new line together if one of the rows approached the edge of the container.

Imagine a two-lane road in an HTML document that wraps both lanes onto a new line together when one of the lanes is full of cars.

Comment: @gogamecocks so if the text in one of the rows are wrapping in 3 lines you want the other row to have a height of 3 rows.. and so on... Am I thinking right?

Comment: I think so. It would be an element that contains more than one row, that wraps whenever the contents of one of those rows begins to overflow its container. On the new line of the element, the rows retain the same stacking order. Basically a ribbon of two colors with the color division down the middle, that wraps like normal lines of text do.

Comment: Now I get it what you are after... maybe- just *maybe* this is possible with some javascript...

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a small trick to do this *without* using anything special such as a `flexbox`:

1. Absolutely position both the `text` and `topic` divs.
2. Adjust the `line-height` and offset one of them with `margin` to create the effect.

```css
.remark{
  position: relative;
}
.text {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 3em;
  margin-top: 1.5em
}
.topic {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 3em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="remark">
    <div>
      <div class="topic">This is the primary row. Ideally, once this row reaches the end of the container, it will wrap to the next line, reserving space for the secondary row, creating effectively two sets of rows of alternating Christmas colors, ho ho ho!</div>
      <div class="text">This is the primary row. Ideally, once this row reaches the end of the container, it will wrap to the next line, reserving space for the secondary row, creating effectively two sets of rows of alternating Christmas colors, ho ho ho!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

For different font-sizes, see this example:

```css
.remark{
  position: relative;
}
.text {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 36px;
  margin-top: 18px;
}
.topic {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 36px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="remark">
    <div>
      <div class="topic">This is the primary row. Ideally, once this row reaches the end of the container, it will wrap to the next line, reserving space for the secondary row, creating effectively two sets of rows of alternating Christmas colors, ho ho ho!</div>
      <div class="text">This is the primary row. Ideally, once this row reaches the end of the container, it will wrap to the next line, reserving space for the secondary row, creating effectively two sets of rows of alternating Christmas colors, ho ho ho!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```